# Where is __LP64__ defined for default builds of C++ applications on OSX 10.6?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, gnu-make

I am building a 3rd-party library in 32-bit mode on OSX 10.6 (the library is Xerces 2.8).  I have determined that the preprocessor definition `__LP64__` is set.  However, as far as I can see it is not being set within any configuration files of the 3rd-party project, and doing a global search through all files (via the Finder) for `#define __LP64__` does not reveal to me where this is being defined by the system.

I am building the library via `make` at the command line (Xcode is not involved).

I would like to know where `__LP64__` is defined - and what its purpose is, given that I am building the project in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's defined automatically by the compiler rather than in any header. If it's set, you're building for 64-bit targets.

(A header *could* define it if the compiler hasn't already, though it shouldn't. If you think this is the case, add `#define __LP64__` to your code, and look at the error during preprocessing to determine the location of the previous define.)

Comment: The command `cpp -dM /dev/null` will give you a list of all of the macros that are defined by your preprocessor.

Comment: `cpp -dM /dev/null` is a gold! Thank you for this.