# Is it possible to build 32-bit applications on OSX 10.6 that run on other OSX 10.6 systems?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, osx-snow-leopard

When building C++ projects using `make` on OSX 10.6, I have determined that the preprocessor definition `__LP64__` seems to be always *automatically* set by the compiler (i.e., it is not defined in any header file) (see [Where is __LP64__ defined for default builds of C++ applications on OSX 10.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721037/where-is-lp64-defined-for-default-builds-of-c-applications-on-osx-10-6)).  This leads to the question: Is it even *possible* to build a 32-bit application on OSX 10.6 that targets (and runs) on another OSX 10.6 system?

I have heard that OSX 10.6 is *always* a 64-bit OS - that it's not even possible to run OSX 10.6 as a 32-bit operating system.  If this is the case, it would make sense that it is *impossible* to build a 32-bit application on OSX 10.6 that will run on another OSX 10.6 system.

I need to know this so I can know whether I'm building a 64-bit application or not (I have been attempting to build my current project as a 32-bit application, since the corresponding Windows version is also being built as 32-bit - but perhaps I need to enable all 64-bit flags and build the OSX 10.6 version of this application as a full-fledged 64-bit application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to do that.  One limited demonstration:

```
$ tar -xf Packages/range-1.14.tgz
$ cd range-1.14
$ ls
COPYING   Makefile  README    gpl-3.0.txt range.c   range.mk  stderr.c  stderr.h
$ rmk CC='gcc -m32'
    gcc -m32 -g     -c stderr.c
    gcc -m32 -g     -c range.c
    gcc -m32 -o range -g     stderr.o range.o  
$ file range
range: Mach-O executable i386
$ rmk -u CC='gcc -m64' 
    gcc -m64 -g     -c stderr.c
    gcc -m64 -g     -c range.c
    gcc -m64 -o range -g     stderr.o range.o  
$ file range
range: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$
```

`rmk -u` is equivalent to (GNU) `make -B`.  This GCC is my home-built 4.6.0.  You can do more with the Apple-provided versions of GCC - like cross-compiling and/or universal builds.

Comment: Thank you.  It was that -m32 flag I was missing.  Indeed I should have known that, or looked at `man make`, but I assumed the `runConfigure` file for the 3rd-party project (which has its own flag for 32-bit builds) would take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X 10.6 runs perfectly well on 32-bit Intel Macs. It dropped support for PowerPC. Future versions of Mac OS X (cough cough NDA cough) may or may not drop support for 32-bit Intel Macs, requiring a 64-bit system.

Even a 64-bit Mac, however, has implicit support for running 32-bit processes, and GCC can cross-compile for i386 targets (or PPC/PPC64/ARMv6/ARMv7 targets.) You must make sure the desired architectures are specified in your build flags however, or it will default to the native architecture (i.e. x86_64.)

If you use the `xcodebuild` command-line utility and pass it the path to an Xcode project bundle, it will automatically use the build settings in the project when calling on GCC. There's rarely a need to use GCC directly on Mac OS X unless you're compiling from generic *NIX sources.

If you tell us why you're using `make` on Mac OS X, we may be able to give you more specific advice, but the preferred command-line compilation method on Mac OS X is still `xcodebuild`.

Comment: I'm using `make` in order to streamline cross-platform builds across both Linux and OSX.  This is a server application with no GUI and only a very small handful of OS-specific calls (mostly embedded within established C++ libraries such as Boost).  Therefore, it's most convenient to have a single procedure defined for the build process that can be followed both on Linux and on OSX.  Otherwise, if building with Xcode, we need two entirely different sets of instructions for the Linux build and the OSX build.  Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: Also, and perhaps more importantly, there are some patch files that have been written for some 3rd-party libraries (Xerces in particular) that modify the configuration files intended for use with `runConfigure` and `make` (but not Xcode), and I would have to go through by hand and make the same changes to the Xcode project settings if I were forced to use Xcode.

Comment: To be more precise, 10.6 dropped support for *booting* on PowerPC machines but nearly all "modern" PPC applications (i.e. those that run on 10.5 or 10.4 outside of the Classic environment) still run fine on 10.6, thanks to Rosetta.  In most cases, it is possible to force the execution environment from the command line by using `arch(1)`, i.e. `arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.6` or `arch -ppc /usr/bin/python2.6`.  That will change in 10.7 apparently.

Comment: Indeed; I was only referring to the hardware on which the OS will run.